How to specify enclosure in Ruby RSS library?
I am trying to use the Ruby RSS library to build an RSS feed for a podcast. I am supplying values for an enclosure, but the enclosure is not being added to the feed and fails silently.
What do I need to do in order for the enclosure to be included in the feed item?
rss = RSS::Maker.make("atom") do |maker|
  maker.channel.id = "my_channel"
  maker.channel.updated = Time.now.to_s
  maker.channel.author = "me"
  maker.channel.title = "my channel"

  maker.items.new_item do |item|
    item.title = "my episode"
    item.id = "my_episode"
    item.updated = Time.now.to_s

    item.enclosure.url = "https://example.com"
    item.enclosure.type = "audio/mpeg"
    item.enclosure.length = 123
  end
end

Output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"        
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">   
  <author>                                       
    <name>me</name>                              
  </author>                                      
  <id>my_channel</id>                            
  <title>my channel</title>                      
  <updated>2024-05-11T12:09:06+01:00</updated>   
  <entry>                                        
    <id>my_episode</id>                          
    <title>my episode</title>                    
    <updated>2024-05-11T12:09:06+01:00</updated> 
    <dc:date>2024-05-11T12:09:06+01:00</dc:date> 
  </entry>                                       
  <dc:date>2024-05-11T12:09:06+01:00</dc:date>
</feed>


You're correct @engineersmnky. Changing "atom" to "2.0" worked. The mandatory channel elements changed from (id, updated, author, title) to (title, description, link) but no other changes were required. If you write your comment up as an answer then I will upvote and accept it.

Your issue is the usage of the Atom maker. Atom does not recognize "enclosure" the same way as the RSS Specs.
Atom can have an "enclosure" by way of a link rel attribute (Spec)
So to use the Atom maker you should be able to do something like
item.link.rel = "enclosure"
item.link.href = "https://example.com"
item.link.type = "audio/mpeg"
item.link.length = 123

Which will generate a Link node like:
 <link rel="enclosure" type="audio/mpeg" length="123" href="https://example.com"/>

If you want to generate a true enclosure node then you will need to use one of the RSS Makers. For Example 2.0 (Spec). Then your existing code will work as anticipated:
RSS::Maker.make("2.0") do |maker|
  # ...
  maker.items.new_item do |item|
    #...
    item.enclosure.url = "https://example.com"
    item.enclosure.type = "audio/mpeg"
    item.enclosure.length = 123
  end
end 

This will generate an enclosure node like:
<enclosure url="https://example.com" length="123" type="audio/mpeg" />

